# read switches usually in while loop

Tags: linux, bash, switch

I want to know the usage of read switches with some good examples.
as instance I know about -t -s -p switches:

```
-t:
he -t option followed by a number of seconds provides an automatic timeout for the read command.
-s:
Usually we can use it for reading password and such things
-p:
prompt..
```

but what is `-r` ?

and do we have another switches?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `-r`: do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

See `help read` for the other options.